# Is it possible to create a slice from an existing reference?

Tags: go

Let's say I have the following function:

```
func foo(bar []int) {
    bar[0] = 456
}
```

I want to create an `[]int` with one element that references `a`, such that when I:

```
var a int = 10
// mySlice := ... crazy hackery?
foo(mySlice)
```

The value of `a` will be 456.

---

I know this is crazy and stupid and not at all the right thing to do. I'm not looking for the "correct" way. The function prototype for `foo` must remain the same.

I can guarantee that while the underlying `int` will change, the slice that points to it is immutable.

The reason for the strange requirement is because this is for the [c2go project](https://github.com/elliotchance/c2go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast any types you want through an `unsafe.Pointer`.

First convert the `*int` to a pointer to an array, then slice it:

```
(*[1]int)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))[:]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bmKcMIj3pb

Comment: As the name suggests, this is **most unsafe indeed**. I can't find nor think of an elegant way to do this - nor should anyone be doing this except in very niche situations (such as in the question). Even so, it seems to be the only solution.